# php send me some variables with addVariable method but i cant get that variables on as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
var myId = this.root.loaderInfo("myId");
```

when i try to catch this variables with AS3 i get this error:

> Error : Attempted access of inaccessible method loaderInfo through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

I also import `flash.display.DisplayObject` but cant get that values from php.

Comment: I just find out how its works.

Comment: I just find out how can i use this loaderInfo 
u guys can use it like
var myId = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters["myId"];

this way u can get the variables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its:

```
trace(this.root.loaderInfo.parameters.myId);
```

loaderInfo is not a method

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but im trying this code's online so i cant use trace. Im trying somethink like this

myTextField.text = "myId= "+myId.toString();

Comment: well, then dont trace the var, but assign it:
var myId = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters.myId

Comment: I just find out how can i use this loaderInfo u guys can use it like var myId = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters["myId"]; this way u can get the variables :)

Comment: yes, because its not a method, as i explained in my answer

Comment: Thanks for help agian :)